# ngInfiniteScroll is not working on huawei honor 7

Tags: html, angularjs, infinite-scroll, nginfinitescroll

ngInfiniteScroll is not working on huawei honor 7,but working fine on some other android device and iphone, and when I test in huawei phone ,it can not find bug.I have no idea how to fix it!so did you meet the same question!
here is my code!

```
<div class="design-items" infinite-scroll="vm.loadMore()"><div class="design-item" ng-repeat="item in vm.skillList" ng-click="vm.goSkillDetail(item)">
  <div class="thumb"><img ng-src="{{item.coverImg | cutImgSize}}" alt=""></div>
  <div class="item-message">
    <div class="item-content">
      <div class="item-title">
        <img class="avatar" ng-src="{{item.skillTplModel.icon}}" alt="">
        <span class="item-name">{{item.skillTplModel.name}}</span>
        <div class="like">
          <img class="people-icon" ng-src="app/resources/images/view_num.png" alt="">
          <span class="people-num">{{item.purchaseNum}}人</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>{{item.skillDescription}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item-likeNum">
      <span class="text-error">{{item.skillFee}}</span>爱意/{{item.skillTplModel.increment || ''}}{{item.skillTplModel.unit}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
vm.loadMore = loadMore;
function loadMore() {
    if (vm.query.page < vm.page.pages) {
        vm.query.page++;
        getSkillList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Did you find solution to your problem? It seems like I've faced with the same issue.

Comment: Yes,I had solve the issue.You can try set infiniteScrollUseDocumentBottom to true!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't resolve my problem. Any way thank you for your help